# Is it good practice to use temporary tables inside a stored procedure or should i use a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I first made a join between two other views to get a third view called AUX that is the one inside the procedure,now im wondering if the use of  three temporary tables inside recipe is a better way to do it.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS recipe;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE recipe(pIDrecipe INT, OUT pmessage VARCHAR(255))
       SALIR:BEGIN
      
          IF pIDrecipe IS NULL THEN
            SET pmessage="wrong input" ;
            LEAVE SALIR;
    
    ELSEIF NOT EXISTS(SELECT pIDrecipe FROM Recipes WHERE IDrecipe = pIDrecipe)  THEN
        SET pmessage="not exists";
        LEAVE SALIR;
       
    ELSE
        START TRANSACTION;
                SELECT Name,ingredients,steps
                FROM AUX WHERE IDrecipe = pIDrecipe;
                SET pmessage="success" ;
         COMMIT;       
     END IF;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I do not see views in your code.

Comment: I wonder if you need views or a procedure at all and the transaction seems to serve no purpose here since there are no changes to the db.

Comment: Committing a select is an interesting concept, maybe if you read [this little tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx/) you will see what transactions are used for

Comment: Is it good practice to use a sproc for things that aren't 'procedural'?

Comment: I was asked to use a stored procedure to solve the problem and i wasn't convinced because i thought that using views was more than enough.

Comment: I would question the use of views too!

Comment: My college mates are using temporary tables inside the procedure to solve the same problem and i thought maybe there is a difference.

Comment: Might be worth telling us the problem you are trying to solve..There really is no such thing as best practice (in this context) Works, efficiently,is maintainable and robust is good though.